# Reporting person who automatically approve suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Take a look in this suggested edit: https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/62621

Obvious gibberish on the verge of spam yet [this member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74314/haim-evgi) (with 13K rep) **has approved it**!

Is it possible to block such members from approving any further suggested edits? Looks like a game for him as he approved 1587 suggestions while rejecting only 93 and it's NOT a game - we should keep the community clean with this power.

If not block, maybe moderator can contact that person and clarify this issue?

Comment: It was health conscious gibberish http://www.alistapart.com/d/usingxml/nutrition_csv.txt

Comment: Good catch - Google, I guess? :)

Comment: @Shadow ... What else?

Comment: For all I know you might be familiar enough with this to know on spot.. ;)

Comment: @Shadow Nope. I was curious about what a _Good Path Egg_ is :)

Comment: I'd guess that he just misclicked, in the stats you can see that he has approved 1592 edits and rejected 93 edits until now.

Comment: @Fabian - This is insane ratio - many suggested edits are nonsense, some harder to spot than others but such ratio point he's not even looking in the edit.

Comment: @Shadow the ratio looks fine for me, but I only approve edits on smaller sites, I have no idea how it looks on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Shadow Also remember that you are not obliged to reject edits. This user _could_ be inclined to approve if he feels like so, and let it pass if he is in doubt. Nothing to censor per se there

Comment: @Wether sorry but on this I disagree.. by approving such edits we cause mess in the community - the suggested edit replaced real question content with total nonsense.

Comment: @Shadow I was not clear enough. I mean: If the user does not want to reject edits, _that_ is ok.  I was positioned on @Fabian hypothesis: _I'd guess that he just misclicked,_ Sorry for the lack of clarity

Comment: @Whether I see now.. it's just that based on the really tiny percentage of rejected edits of that member I can't help thinking he's automatically approving. Normal approve/reject rate IMO should be around 70/30 or worst case 90/10 but not 95/5 like that.

Comment: @Shadow maybe he has a policy of approving only what he likes, and leaving everything else to others. A cursory look through his profile doesn't show any other such incidents, and he is fairly active editing and approving, so it's possible he just misclicked. Remember that approving doesn't gain any points.

Comment: I will invite him here through a comment

Comment: Thanks @Pekka - hope that's the case indeed.

Comment: The edit **was rejected** anyway, so the system works. Even if it had been accepted, the next person could roll it back again.

Comment: @BoPersson - it was rejected because I've voted to reject in addition to someone else. But if someone else would have approved as well, it could easily pass through and never be noticed.

Comment: This should be rolled into a generic "people should lose privileges they fail at" request; suggested edits aren't particularly special

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If this is an isolated case, shrug it off. It could simply be a misclick. The suggested edit interface is quite risk-prone, not only because of the usual problem with two buttons next to each other, but also because decided edits scroll away so if you're fast you might end up clicking in the right column but on the wrong row.

Looking through [this user's recent reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/74314/haim-evgi?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_reviews), he rejected 4 of his most recent 90 reviews, and approved against the flow 5 times:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/60708)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/61247)
[3](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/61335)
[4](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/62610)
[5](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/62621).
4 and 5 should have been obvious rejects; 3 looks like an honest mistake, and 1 and 2 look borderline.

Haim: You need to be more careful when reviewing edit suggestions. Take an extra couple of seconds on each edit to make sure you select the right button, and don't hesitate to skip if you're unsure. It's not as if you won't be reaching the 30/day limit anyway.

Shadow: a 95% approve rate isn't so surprising if someone only approves obvious formatting and English improvements and skips other cases. (Ok, that's not far from my behavior and I have a 75% approve rate, but I'm on the side of rejecting trivial edits.)

Comment: Thanks, good answer and well said. Guess I'm the more active/argumentative type aka rejecting more..