# An overturned "Looks Good" review gets too little feedback to improve reviewing

Tags: discussion, review, deleted-answers, low-quality-posts

I've done a few reviews of Low Quality Posts. At one point I clicked "Looks Good", but it turned out someone (or the system?) disagreed. It may have been an honest mistake on my part, or perhaps I just disagree with the other person. However, my meta question is not about whether I was wrong or not.

This question is about whether the feedback I got can be improved. There are two things I noticed:

- The next view I got explained that someone/something disagreed with me, and that I *should review* this discrepancy. However, the answer was deleted in the mean time, and I *can't see deleted answers*, so I couldn't reflect on my "mistake". See this screenshot:

---

[image: feedback without answer]

---

- When I tried to reload the page from my browser history, I got a similar screen, which had an additional confusing element: apparently the only review was mine? I had expected to see other reviewers that recommended deletion? See this screenshot:

---

[image: no other reviewers]

---

My question is: can feedback for this situation be improved? I'd love to review my decision and improve my post reviews.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That post had been flagged as spam *outside* of the review queue, and deleted long before you reviewed it. The [answer in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019990) (10k+ only) was deleted by a moderator, shortly after it was posted:

[image: spammy message, deleted]

It probably should not have been shown in the queue in the first place. A bug, in other words.

However, if it was placed in the queue intentionally (in order to teach reviewers about what spam can look like), then you've found a bug in that it should've shown you what the post looks like when you were admonished for not having recommended deletion.

One way or the other, the review queue should handle this better.

Comment: Thanks, this was the info I was after. I did make a review mistake then :O tsk tsk. Would be good to hear from those who know whether this should've been in the queue or not, and if so whether we this situation could show a one-time peek at the deleted answer, for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually [by design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152709/improving-the-quality-of-reviews-project-honeypot): the answer you saw was a previously deleted spam answer that was inserted into the review queue as an automated test of your reviewing accuracy.

What is clearly a bug, however, is that you couldn't see the answer on the "test failed" page.  You should either edit your question to focus on that aspect, or post a separate question about it (with the tags [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [review-audits](/questions/tagged/review-audits)).