# Questions about review testing

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

While reviewing, I sometimes get test-results. Flagging them typically will show the following:

> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention.
>   The post has already been removed, but if it hadn't your response
>   would have helped to ensure that it was. Thanks!

I just had it happen in "First Posts", but recall seeing it with some of the other review types as well, and sometimes multiple times within the same reviewing session. I assume they are meant to prevent review-abuse by users harvesting badges who just click the same review action repeatedly.

I'm just curious about a few things:

- I assume some type of review options are better suited for these tests than others. I cannot see it work on "Suggested Edits", for example. Is this the case?
- What happens if I accidentally would miss-click? Will I be punished in any way?
- Does the fact I keep seeing these tests every now and then imply I might have marked some answers wrongly, or do they show for absolutely everyone?

(Note: I'm not trying to figure out how to sidestep the system. Just curious).

Edit: Another question, actually. What reply does one get when missing it's a honeypot answer? I don't think I ever encountered one of those occasions, but that could be because I just caught the honeypot questions. Is there a "Whoops, you screwed the pooch on that one" message, too?

Comment: Given the recent issues with people blowing through the review queue and upvoting garbage, thank you for passing the test.

Comment: How long has the tests been going on; is he the first one to pass? :D

Comment: @George: FWIW, slightly less than 9% of audits in the First Posts queue have failed so far. That's 191 failures, and a total of 148 users, with most failing only once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was I told, "Congratulations, this was only a test" when reviewing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/why-was-i-told-congratulations-this-was-only-a-test-when-reviewing)

Comment: I just "failed a test" that I thought was an OK [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741246/need-help-changing-my-package-name-in-eclipse). Frankly, I think the "powers that be" have got some things wrong. IT wasn't a great post, but it was acceptable and conveyed useful info.

Comment: These tests also seem to be rather too frequent. I just processed about 8-10 Suggested Edits and hit 2 "tests". I'd expect one... two in such a short time frame seems overkill.

Comment: I agree that they seem too frequent. The more careful a reviewer is in considering each question, the more time they waste per test question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I assume some type of review options are better suited for these tests than others. I cannot see it work on "Suggested Edits", for example. Is this the case?

Yes, Shog [mentions the honeypot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152716/133693) is right now present for Low Quality Posts and First posts review queue

> Will I be punished in any way?

<s>As of now, the failures are logged, but no actions are taken. I wouldn't be surprised if this was changed later.</s>

There are automated review suspensions [in place now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/review-suspension/info), so if you fail too many review audits you'll be automatically banned from reviewing

> Does the fact I keep seeing these tests every now and then imply I might have marked some answers wrongly, or do they show for absolutely everyone?

I haven't run into these often(they get swooshed before I can even look) but I do believe this is shown for all, to keep the reviewers on their toes and to reduce [robo-reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=robo%20reviewers&submit=search)

Comment: I could guess it was in for the 'First Posts' review queue. I've been seeing many fewer votes for obvious spam lately, overall.