# What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?

Tags: support, faq, review, review-audits

I sometimes receive this rather amusing message while reviewing in the review queues:

> #### Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. **You passed.**

If I am not paying attention while reviewing I sometimes receive this not-so-amusing message:

> #### STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. **You didn't pass.**
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

- What is the purpose of this test?
- How does the audit work?
- What happens if I fail?
- Why was the system expecting me to negatively review a good post, or positively review a bad post?
- A review is obviously an audit. Should I report it?
- Do review audits count toward the Reviewer badge?
- Do robo-reviewers [dream of electric sheep?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_Androids_Dream_of_Electric_Sheep%3F)

---

[Return to FAQ index](/q/7931)

Answer (score 301, accepted):

### What is the purpose of this test?

The test (known as a *review audit*) is designed to help new reviewers hone their moderation skills, while nudging more experienced users who don't seem to be paying close attention to what they're reviewing. Some people were in the habit of positively reviewing everything without regard to quality; extremely low-quality posts with a high score are very problematic in a system where the best information naturally rises to the top, so "audit" tasks are mixed in to make sure folks are paying attention.

This is currently active only on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/), [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), and [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

### How does the audit work?

- ***First questions***, ***First answers***, ***Late answers***, ***Triage***, and ***Low quality posts/answers***: The test presents a reviewer with a post that was previously deleted and known to be of extremely poor quality (flagged as spam, "not an answer", or "very low quality"), or known to be of high quality (many up-votes, no down-votes, etc).
- ***Close votes*** and ***Reopen votes***: The test presents a reviewer with a question which the system has determined should be open or closed based on various criteria (highly-voted with no close votes, quickly closed with no answers, etc).
- ***Suggested edits***: The test presents a reviewer with a randomly generated edit utilizing the Markov chain algorithm to randomly insert various words that may appear to be useful at first glance but actually make no sense and are meant to vandalize the post.

If a user passes a test, they are informed that they passed and thanked for their time and feedback. If a user fails a review audit, they are warned that they didn't pass and encouraged to pay more attention in the future.

The result is then recorded for analysis. Only diamond (♦) moderators or Stack Exchange employees can see the full data; it is not accessible publicly even to high-reputation users. Normal users can see if a given post was used to generate audits in the post's timeline; the entry will appear as "audit", and clicking on it will access the review task which will indicate the pass/fail outcome and the user to whom it was presented.

### What happens if I fail?

For most, [nothing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156938/stop-look-and-listen-audit-tricked-me/156942#comment452398_156942). You'll be given some guidance on why the post was inappropriate and what you could have done instead, and then allowed to continue reviewing.

[image: STOP]

Repeated failures, especially in short succession, can [lead to your review privileges being suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158675/why-am-i-getting-the-message-youve-failed-too-many-recent-review-audits#158675) for a few days or longer, depending on the frequency of the failures. Stack Exchange is continuing to analyze the data to determine the best action to take in these cases.

### Why was the system expecting me to perform the wrong action on a post?

Review audits are *chosen automatically*. The system isn't perfect, meaning that every so often a post slips through normal community detection and moderation, causing the system to generate a bad, invalid, or questionable audit.

These can be split into two cases:

**The system expected me to positively review a bad post**

- The most common case is when a low-quality, off-topic, or otherwise close-worthy post gets upvoted. Sometimes visitors may upvote posts without paying attention to the site rules.
- You identify a post as being an exact duplicate of an older, highly-voted post. To prevent audits from being obvious, the vote count is displayed as zero and the user card is either anonymized or shown as having been posted by a new user. This may make you think you are looking at an exact duplicate.

**The system expected me to negatively review a good post**

- Other users may have cast subjective downvotes, which means they disagree with the post rather than think it is a bad post. You may have had a different opinion, or attempted to review it objectively.
- The post may have been marked as spam as part of a spamming attack where only a few users knew the details. In this case, moderators can clear the spam flags, to prevent them from being used as audits.<sup>1</sup>

*Don't worry!* The fact that you identified a bad audit means that you are paying attention, and are not the type of reviewer that the audits are intended to catch.

If you encounter a bad audit, **post it on the per-site meta** tagged [support](/questions/tagged/support)[disputed-review-audits](/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) to draw attention to it, containing a **link to either the audit review task or the post**, and **why you disagree with the audit**. Other users can cast votes to counteract the automatic decisions that led to it being chosen as the wrong type of audit (e.g. downvote and close an off-topic question that got picked as a known-good audit). If you get suspended from reviewing as a result of failing one or more bad audits, the review suspension can be lifted or shortened by ♦ moderators at their discretion.

### A review is obviously an audit. Should I report it?

There are many ways to identify audits (e.g. click to see the post itself, the user, the vote count, etc.). Almost all of these ways involve having to further investigate the post. By this time, you've already carefully reviewed the post, which is the intent of the queues.

As stated earlier, the main purpose of audits is to catch robo-reviewers, who mindlessly review without even looking at the posts, and to help educate new reviewers. Easy-to-identify audits help legitimate reviewers pass and help better hone new reviewers' skills.

On the other hand, if you spot a user who appears to be gaming the system (e.g. they are making bad reviews but somehow passing every audit) flag one of their posts for moderator attention and explain the situation; moderators will take a further look and maybe issue a manual review suspension.

Also, if you find something in the review audit system that makes audits *extremely* obvious (as in one can *immediately* tell that a review is an audit, with almost *no* extra investigation), feel free to report that flaw.

### Do review audits count towards review badges?

Passed audits count as a successful review towards the review badges. A failed audit does not count toward the badges, but does not decrement your progress either; it simply adds none.

### Do robo-reviewers dream of electric sheep?

Robo-reviewers don't sleep. They *wait.*

#### Important Note:

*The information contained in this answer is subject to change as the review system is further refined. Changes that impact the mechanics of the test, or consequences of failing it repeatedly will be reflected in this answer as they're made, but not necessarily immediately after they're made.*

---

<sup>1. In December 2018, a [change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377864/839601) was made where only posts that are deleted by the system in response to the threshold number of spam flags (currently four from normal users or a single one from a moderator) will be used as known-spam audits in the *Triage* and *Low quality posts (answers)* queues (as well as entirely excluding posts with one or more valid "rude or abusive" flags in those queues). However, you may still see this happen, e.g. if the flags come from [Charcoal](https://charcoal-se.org/) users, as well as in other review queues.</sup>

Comment: I'd like a "I still disagree, your test if flawed" button for "failed" tests.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: keep in mind, these test posts have already been *deleted* - so if you disagree strongly, you should probably flag them for moderator attention / bring them up on Meta / etc.

Comment: I got the "failed" message when closing some questions. It presented a real one and I clicked on the "Close" button just to see how many other people had considered it a "closable" question, but it immediately said I failed the test despite not yet submitting a close vote... I quite often open that close dialog up just to see what other people are thinking (in the event I am overlooking why the question is being voted to be closed).

Comment: @dreamlax You should not review based on what others are thinking, because that only amplifies existing reviews. The review systems works because multiple people form an independent opinion. If there is (semi-)consensus that probably means the consensus is true and actions can be based on that consensus. However, if that "consensus" is because everyone agrees with the ones before him only the first independant opinion determines the consensus and thus it becomes worthless.

Comment: @dtech: I see your point and fair enough. For me though, I don't blindly follow what everyone else is thinking, I only check to see if perhaps my mind has had a severe lapse of judgement.

Comment: Can users ever graduate out of having to take these tests?  I've done hundreds of reviews, and have passed every test thrown at me.  How long before the system figures out that I can recognize garbage? Maybe when I earn the Steward badge?

Comment: @Barmar They're actually shown on a purely random basis. It's conceivable that even a seasoned reviewer might find themselves just going through the motions once in a while, and that's precisely what these are designed to catch. If you've been consistently passing them, then you have nothing to worry about. And _by_ consistently passing them, you help us learn a little more about how people use the review system.

Comment: I suppose. It just feels a little condescending after a while.

Comment: I just failed my first audit by clicking "no action needed", on an answer that had already been deleted, which I knew by clicking through to the full question. Because my understanding of reviewing was to recommend future action (or to take action myself), I concluded that the problem had already been resolved, so no further action was needed. Have I misunderstood the purpose of reviewing, such that I shouldn't be looking at the live post to see the current state of affairs in its larger context? Is my misunderstanding of a different flavour? Advice/clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it theoretically possible for the random algorithm to generate helpful edit suggestions? And, if that happens to me, can that be taken as conclusive proof that this is the matrix, and I am the Chosen One?

Comment: I was thinking about posting a new question, but hopefully a comment here will suffice. My problem with this is that I sometimes want to view some close reasons, which I can do before closing, **except** when these tests occur. I wanted to check if something was a duplicate by opening the **close** dialog, but was then "busted".

Comment: @Keyser Don't worry about occasionally hitting them as long as you're actually paying attention. Nothing bad will happen if you do that once in a while, it's sort of expected.

Comment: @TimPost Thanks for the quick answer. Sounds good :) If you ever decide to use this system to exclude bad reviewers you might want to look it over though :p

Comment: @TimPost When was this implemented exactly? I had the feeling I got these tests more often of late than I used to, but that could be because it's a recent feature...

Comment: Does failing review audits on a single type of review cause suspension on every type of review. (e.g. If I fail few review audits on First Posts review then will I suspended from every review queue or just from First Posts review?)

Comment: Pffiew, happy to have read this. (I failed an audit because I was curious how much close votes an obvious good question got.)

Comment: @dtech Your point, that reviews should not be based on what others think, is correct. However, consider this case: I notice a question has had close votes, but see nothing wrong with it. Before I comment "*this post is fine*", I'd like to see why it was close-voted in the first place. For instance, it's considered a duplicate, and maybe it is? So I take a look at the linked post to double-check. It is only then that I can decide whether the post truly was a duplicate, or if people may have misjudged the post; maybe they only *look* similar, but actually ask 2 different things?

Comment: If we shouldn't take other people's votes into consideration, why are they shown at all? Mind you, I'm not arguing that we should take other people's votes into consideration; I'm suggesting that the system shouldn't encourage that behavior by showing us those votes. The big exception there is duplicate votes. For those we _should_ take other people's votes into consideration, because it's entirely plausible that a well-formed question is a duplicate, but that I don't know it because I'm not familiar with that tag. In fact, maybe dupe votes should be in their own queue?

Comment: I would very much like an "I respectfully disagree" button added to the failure dialog. I suppose it may be a character flaw, but if someone solicits my opinion (as SO does by asking me to review things), and then tells me I'm wrong, I expect a chance to argue my position. It just seems polite.

Comment: Just to clarify - are the bans always manual, or are there automatic ones as well? In either case, could "What happens if I fail?" be updated? If there's an automatic ban, presumably the algorithm is secret - can it be explicitly stated that it is?

Comment: I suspect that one real consequence of these audits is to encourage active members _not_ to review.  I decided to be a good citizen and do my share and clear off the review list whenever presented.  But when you get one or two of these stupid and condescending responses a day, I decided whats the f\*\*\*ing point and gave up reviewing.  How many others have done likewise? You don't get anything for acting as a reviewer other than be insulted by the system for your contribution.

Comment: I don't get these at all; if the point isn't to go along with the herd, then what's the point of the test?  If 5 people said a question is poor and should be closed, but I don't think it should be, then there's a disconnect.  Either you are encouraging groupthink or you encourage people to make their own decisions, but the fact there's some hidden algorithm that determines if you reviewed "correctly" defeats the purpose of thinking independently.

Comment: @dtech - I think it largely depends on how you approach reviewing.  I first review the question, form my opinion, then do a check against the views of others to see if I actually disagree with them or not.  I am open to convincing if I look at the question in a new way when I see a strong leaning towards a particular reason, but it has to be enough to convince me the reason is valid.  It may also help sway me on borderline questions, maybe I think it is borderline on being too broad, but if the votes were for dupe, then I would leave open, but if 4 people voted too broad, I'd close.

Comment: @dreamlax doesn't matter if you don't blindly follow. It's something proven: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asch_conformity_experiments

Comment: And what appens if I **pass** the audit?
Trying to understand [why the **rejected suggested edits count** of a reviewer returned to 1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251640/user-rejected-edit-suggestions-is-changed) I saw that the [reviewer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/152786/smathy) passed [**this test**](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7382106).
Does the **rejected suggested edits count** return to **0 or 1** if the audit is passed?

Comment: If in doubt, skip.

Comment: Yea I just got my review rights removed for a little because someone posted a question asking about how to make a plugin work and linked to some sites. I looked at the URLs and they weren't sites for selling something. So I said it required editing. But I failed since the question was closed. Its just confusing to me. It wasn't spam. And I went and looked at the question again and others had commented that it seemed to be a legit question too. Very aggravating. Try to help the community by doing your share and I am being punished for it.

Comment: @TimPost Hi, Can you please clarify [Why audits are not extended to SE communities other than the ones mentioned here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10026/why-is-there-no-review-audit-on-scifi-fantasy-stack-exchange) ? It would be really great if you would answer it on the SFF Meta post I created in this regard.

Comment: "The system expected me to negatively review a good post." This will be seen often on math (dot) stackexchange (dot) com. A fairly small clique does a moderately good job of identifying bad posts in cases where it's easy to make that judgment, but in all cases where a little bit of subtlety is involved, they identify the post as garbage by knee-jerk reflex. They are sometimes extraordinarily hostile to disagreement with their decisions in such cases.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18136902 There is still some flaw. I got tricked by Audit test for this Late answer today. It fits the category of explaining a short detail and than posting a link to provide the answer to the question still I failed the test.

Comment: A bronze badge would be nice, for passing the tests

Comment: I posted a suggestion for the question in a comment on a high quality post, but it declared I failed the audit because I should have left it alone or up voted it. Should I not post comments on good posts in review queues? I think that comments shouldn't be counted as negative interactions. Just neutral.