# What is the aftermath of not passing the review tests?

Tags: discussion, review, review-abuse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was I told, “Congratulations, this was only a test” when reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/why-was-i-told-congratulations-this-was-only-a-test-when-reviewing)

I've noticed that while browsing the reviews tasks, sometimes a fake answer/question appears to test whether you are just randomly browsing or are actually paying attention.

What is the aftermath of not passing or passing it? Could not passing it lead to something permanent (such as being banned from the review tasks work)?

As a side question: How important should this tests be considered?

Comment: Nothing. Possibly in the future. Very.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/why-was-i-told-congratulations-this-was-only-a-test-when-reviewing

Comment: If you fail the test you will be put to death. Summary execution. No appeal. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment there is no aftermath as such. The review tests are still being worked on.

Later on, depending on the responses recorded, review tests may have a bearing on privileges and rep (guess), but thats still quite some time away.