# Encourage people to pay attention while reviewing

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, badge-request, review-audits

Recently I saw a "No action needed" button in the review system, which I think is really good for stopping bad/fake upvotes from the people who are striving just for badges. Still they can easily bypass by just clicking the same button without actually paying attention to the question.

So for a remedy, We could also have a system like so,

> #### Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. This post
> has already been removed, but thanks for taking time to leave feedback for the
> author.

and

[image: Stop]

What I suggest is providing 3 (Bronze/Silver/Gold) badges on **Congratulations** counting. i.e. same as review system.

As

1. Congratulation - Bronze Badge
2. 250 Congratulations - Silver Badge
3. 1000 Congratulations - Gold Badge

And for Not paying attention remove 1 reputation per every few attentions.

Maybe in this way we can get more attention from people who are just striving for Badges.

Attribution : Stop Image taken from [accepted answer of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/why-was-i-told-congratulations-this-was-only-a-test-when-reviewing)

Comment: [Downvotes shows disagreement on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Badges ruined the whole thing in the first place, please please please don't add any more!

Comment: @Jennis Voting is anonymous on *all* of the sites.  Please don't ask for comments on downvotes, no one is obliged to answer, and the request is considered *noise*, even on meta.

Comment: @JollyOldSaintNicholas Agreed. Will keep in mind. Thax

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. You already get the review-related badges if you are reviewing properly. Audits are just checking that you are reviewing properly. Hitting "No action needed" when there *is* action needed means that you're not reviewing properly -- on an audit review, that's a fail. There's no reason to add intermediate badges for something that's already rewarded by a badge.

Comment: Actually my point was like still people go with just clicking the button "No action needed". Is this what they get badges for ? What do you say ?

Comment: Clicking "No action needed" when the post does need action counts (or _should_, if for some reason it doesn't) as a failed audit.

Comment: It adds count to your total review queue. How does it become failed audit than ? And badge striving people just succeed in that.

Comment: Does clicking "No action needed" result in "Congratulations" or "STOP look and listen" when the review is an audit?

Comment: Got it now :D Thax