# Do tests in the review tasks count towards the Reviewer badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why was I told, “Congratulations, this was only a test” when reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/why-was-i-told-congratulations-this-was-only-a-test-when-reviewing)

Occasionally, when performing [a review task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/) at Stack Overflow, I'll notice that a "test question" is injected to make sure I'm paying attention. Does completing these test questions count towards the Reviewer badge? The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) on badges doesn't exactly make that clear.

Comment: My guess would be no. It wouldn't make sense for them to. I'll let you know next time I see one, though.

Comment: "***Do test reviews count toward the Reviewer badge?**

Passed tests count as a successful review toward the Reviewer badge. A failed test does not count toward the badge, but does not decrement your progress, it simply adds none.*"

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as a duplicate. Seems like a fairly specific question.