# Why is there no feedback for Suggested Edits review audits?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-audits, feedback

This is a follow up to [a question I asked yesterday about what I perceived as vandalism on posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170140/anybody-knows-why-people-bots-vandalize-posts):

Why is it that we don't get feedback if we succeed at a Suggested Edit review audit?

For example, I got [an audit on First Posts today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/1653258), and upon my correctly identifying the post as incorrect, I got the following message:

> Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You passed. This post has already been removed, but if it hadn't, your flag would have helped to ensure that it was. Thanks!

And if I had got it wrong, I would have gotten the "STOP! READ AND LEARN!" message.

So again, why not for Suggested Edits? Is this on purpose? If so, what's the purpose? And if it's not, can we suggest that such messages be implemented for Suggested Edits review audits?

**EDIT**

It's been pointed out that this question is a duplicate of [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165924/is-there-supposed-to-be-feedback-on-edit-review-audits). While it's true of the main question, I believe the sub-questions are new. Let me repeat/rephrase them:

- Are we not seeing a message indicating that we successfully passed an audit on purpose?

  - If we don't see a message on purpose, what is the purpose?
  - If it's not on purpose where can I make a suggestion to the dev to add it?

I would also like to point out that the sole (unaccepted) answer given in the original question is rather poor as it only says there's some feedback when a user fails the audit. It also not answers the points I raised above.

Comment: do you say suggested edits don't show 'STOP! READ AND LEARN!' or 'Congratulations' messages? I thought I see these every day...

Comment: Well, I never failed a "vandalism" suggested edit, so I don't know if they show on failure. They sure don't show the "Congratulation" message on success, though.

Comment: I can confirm that you don't get a 'Congratulations' message on the 'Low Quality Posts', I think I was wrong. (but 'STOP! READ AND LEARN!' is shown, I sure of that)

Comment: I believe that currently on the First Posts and Late Answers queues give the "Congratulations" feedback. I've never seen it anywhere else.

Comment: The question is indeed similar. The answer given isn't satisfying, though.

Comment: @animuson any reason why only First Posts and Late Answers and not the other types of reviews? Why the inconsistency?