# Is the lack of positive feedback for Suggested Edits reviews audits intentional?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-audits, feedback

So it seems that [my question about review audits feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170320/why-is-there-no-feedback-for-suggested-edits-review-audits) from yesterday was shut down because it was too similar to a [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165924/is-there-supposed-to-be-feedback-on-edit-review-audits) (for which I must add the sole answer to was less than satisfactory). So let me rephrase the question in a more focused fashion:

- Is there a lack of positive feedback for Suggested Edits reviews audits on purpose?

  - If it's on purpose, what is the purpose?
  - If it's not, how should I/we do to get this feature implemented?

Comment: Since you're asserting that this should be changed, why do you feel that it's important to provide this positive feedback?  What benefits would it provide?

Comment: It would allow me (or other reviewers) not to come to Meta and ask about the crazy number of users or bots that are trying to introduce vandalism at an alarming rate!

Comment: It would also be consistent with the types of reviews for which the audits provide a positive feedback.

Comment: Thank you for posting such an awesome question.  Please accept 5 Internet dollars as a token of our appreciation. (+1)

Comment: I have not noticed that as a problem.  If it becomes a problem at some point in the future, then perhaps we can address it then.

Comment: @Servy So if _you_ don't think it's a problem, then it's not a problem?

Comment: @Joce No, I'm saying I haven't noticed people making requests of that nature on meta.  Do you have links to a significant number of such posts, to the point where it's clearly disruptive to the meta community?  I'm not saying those posts aren't bad, I'm saying they just aren't being posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It is on purpose. We kinda felt it was unnecessary given how blatantly bad the audits are.
2. If you think they'd be useful, post that as a feature-request and describe why you'd like to see them.

Comment: I personally think it comes down to a UX / user expectation thing. Being told that I correctly flagged a late answer (for example), I come to expect to be told when I correctly passed any and all types of audits. 
I would say SO should either be silent or be explicit for every types of audits.

Comment: FYI: feature-request posted. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170528/add-a-positive-feedback-for-all-types-of-review-audits