# Add a positive feedback for all types of review audits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, review-audits, feedback

In my [continuing series](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170140/anybody-knows-why-people-bots-vandalize-posts) of [posts about review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170519/is-the-lack-of-positive-feedback-for-suggested-edits-reviews-audits-intentional), here's what I learnt so far:

- [StackOverflow is not being used to train machine learning algorithms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170141/160667)
- [The lack of feedback from successfully passing a Suggested Edit review audit is intentional](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170521/160667)

I have to say I feel the lack of positive feedback for Suggested Edit review audits is inconsistent from what one comes to expect from successfully passing a review audit for other types of reviews (the ones where proper flagging is expected).

As a user, I would expect the feedback to be consistent from one type to the next. This is this lack of consistency that brought be to ask a question about what I thought was rampant vandalism attempts on SO.

That brings be to ask for this feature: Add feedback to for correctly identifying a review audit for Suggested Edits (and for any other types of reviews that don't currently provide such a positive feedback).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there supposed to be feedback on edit-review audits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165924/is-there-supposed-to-be-feedback-on-edit-review-audits) - though this is the second time this has come up *today* - maybe needs some attention!

Comment: @Rory This is not a duplicate as this is a feature request that stems from a [follow up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170519/is-the-lack-of-positive-feedback-for-suggested-edits-reviews-audits-intentional)  to the post you mention.

Comment: I would rather see that I got my vote back when passing, so I can reject a real  vandalism edit instead.

Comment: It looks like they've [meta-tag:status-completed] this. I just got a "congratulations" in the suggested edits queue.

Comment: @animuson I got it too! (yay!) Who's role is it to mark the feature request as "status-completed"?

Comment: @Joce: Usually [the person who announces it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170820).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been implemented: we now give feedback after *all* audits, pass or fail.

Answer (score 3):

I think they should give rep for passing audits, and a shiny badge for passing many of them.

This would really motivate those whose sole purpose in going through the review queue are the badges.

Nobody who wants more rep would want to lose an opportunity for it because they missed an audit, so they will pay more attention to what they are doing.

Comment: Or, users will just click-through to every post looking for audits and skip everything else...

Comment: @animuson, I suppose they could, but they're probably still going for the normal review badges.

Comment: There should not be badges for passing audits. There should be sanctions for failing them. You already get badges for review -- the audits are just there to make sure you're doing it properly. Extra credit for passing audits implies that they are somehow optional, within the scope of review activity; they are not.

Answer (score -2):

Ugh. What's the point of positive feedback? Especially on suggested edit audit reviews, which are blatantly obvious in the first place? I don't need to be told that it's an audit, thank you very much. Give me feedback if something interesting happens, i.e. if I feel a review. If I pass, I don't need my attention brought to it. It's a waste of time and attention.

[Remove positive feedback from review audits.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182722/stop-bothering-me-with-suggested-edit-review-audits)

Comment: If you don't know audits exist at all, then you need "positive" feedback to know what the heck is going on.

Comment: @djechlin Then show them once. I've seen hundreds of them. I'm sick of them.