# review section I think has a bug

Tags: support, review, review-audits

Sometimes in review section Stack Overflow tests us to find out that we are paying attention or not.

We can pass this test by clicking 'flag' if it says congratulation it is a test if it does not say so it is not a test.

And another way we can click 'edit' if it says this post cannot be edited so it means this is a test.

I'm asking the question. Is the test for checking if we are paying attention or not? So as I said a person can pass the test without paying attention.

Comment: could not tell me please why you have puted that vote downs to me?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are for this being somewhat of a duplicate - there have been many such "bugs" reported earlier. Perhaps not **specifically** for flagging, but nonetheless. Or simply for disagreeing that pressing "flag" is not paying attention. I dunno. =)

Comment: I can't see how anyone would press flag or edit if they aren't paying attention. ("Not paying attention" in the audit context means "didn't even read the suggested edit".)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason the [review tests (audit)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) were created was to catch people who were up voting or clicking the Approve button without reading the question or answer properly and to remind them to be more careful. If you're trying to edit the question or answer then you are showing at some level that you aren't blindly up voting or approving so perhaps it's not so important what happens in that case.

Answer (score 2):

The review audits are here to counter the robo-reviewers that are constantly clicking the simplest option (approve in suggested edits). Yes you can cheat the test by clicking flag or edit (and there are more). But all cheats require you to perform at least one extra action. So this will stop the robo reviewers. Or at least hinder them.