# There's no review audits for duplicate

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, review-audits

[FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) says there's audits for Close Votes queue. But I've noticed there's no audits when you filter to duplicates only.

Is it intentionally?

Comment: Seems to be the case, just did my 40 today with duplicate filter on and didn't get a single audit either.  Perhaps duplicate audits would be too obvious, and/or given duplicates inherently require *more* time than normal close votes it's sufficiently obvious when someone is screaming through one from # of reviews/time period that audits aren't necessary?

Comment: I don't see why duplicate audits would be any *more obvious* than the suggested edit audits. We're not trying to trick people, just make sure that they're paying attention @joe

Comment: They'd be either more or less obvious than other close audits, because they have to include a duplicate.  I guess you could choose random questions and random duplicates, but if you're looking for voted-against-duplicates that aren't debatable, I think you'd have a hard time finding good (obvious but not too obvious) ones automatically.

Comment: Another possible duplicate audit would be to simply give an *exact* duplicate as target, same user and everything. Maybe a new word in the title so its clear that there are two questions. Like @CodyGray, said audits arent tricks just tests to check that you are awake.