# Building guided tour on how to review?

Tags: feature-request, review, tour

When I had enough rep to review I had no idea how that works. I looked at it and said: *Ok, I come back in a few months when I have a clue about it.*

I could of course have read a handful of meta posts about it, but I was too lazy for that.

Long story short: I am sure many users would review but have no idea about it or they start reviewing and don't do a good job at it.

#### Please build a guided tour on how to review.

- It could be like the site tour we already have.
- And include some example test reviews to explain common scenarios
- We could also give a badge for taking the tour

@ShaWizDowArd provided a possible mockup (thanks):

[image: mockup]

Comment: And I'm pretty sure that this idea got converted into a question after [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209262/216721) was posted! :) Really nice thought, +1.

Comment: [Mockup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6XTMF.png) - feel free to embed into the question if you also agree. :)

Comment: And it needs to have this as background music: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hnrsqf33MXA

Comment: In the same vein I've noticed they randomly throw in a "test" review after which they say "was to see if you were awake". I passed but I always wondered what would have happened if I had failed...

Comment: @Machavity [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121)