# Improving spam posts with approved suggested edit

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, spam

Not having seen this before, it struck me as horrific that a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1173495/sann3) would actually [suggest an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4163721) to a [spam post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882856/comment-icon-not-updating-after-approval-in-blog-site/22032085#22032085) to correct link markdown, and it was unanimously approved!

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3326262/khadizakhatun) posted some spam, but didn't get their link markdown correct:

> [image: answer post]

So, it was kindly suggested to correct the spam link:

> [image: suggested-edit]

Which was then unanimously approved:

> [image: approved]

Am I missing something, or is this magnitude of oversight concerning?

Comment: **SUSPEND ALLLLL THE REVIEWERS!** Holy crap.

Comment: I...what...how?! And I thought accepting too many minor edits was annoying.

Comment: Actually, looking at the edit, the kicker is that I don't think the edited version got the markdown completely right either.

Comment: @Charles: I think warning or short-time suspension would do it, too, unless they were already warned. Also, giving suspensions would not solve the issue on its own. We would need more restrict reviews for cases, like this, too.

Comment: @LaszloPapp I think I read that accepting a spam edit triggers an auto-suspension. I assume Charles is advocating that the criteria be expanded a bit.

Comment: @DennisMeng how come not?

Comment: @LaszloPapp, I disagree, but perhaps that's why I'm not a mod.  
We have roboreviewers that aren't even bothering to understand the context of the edits they're approving.  That's nonsense, and I'm sick and tired of reviewbots like them approving crap edits.  Kill them all.

Comment: @JanDvorak They didn't delete the `</a>`

Comment: @LaszloPapp Nah, I would suspend their review privileges for a while. This is beyond stupid. Sounds harsh, but I hope these guys are not writing code. This approval was so bad it makes me wonder if they are sock puppet accounts - sounds far fetched but how could 3 consecutive reviewers get this so wrong?

Comment: @DennisMeng oh. Good eye

Comment: @slugster: have you considered the option that one of them pressed the wrong button due to UX shortcomings, the two buttons being too close to each other? I did such mistakes in the past when I had not wanted. They probably were not in such cases, but that is immaterial. Anyway, punishing people one by one is not a long term solution. I am still surprised there are no better audits. It feels a bit tedious to read these threads all the time, and there are probably more not revealed by people that could be by proper audits.

Comment: @slugster by not looking at where the URL leads, perhaps? Or maybe they were consecutive because those who did notice were busy flagging the post? Oh, and that^

Comment: You people seriously underestimate just how *bad* the suggested edit problem is on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn is it apocalyptically bad, or bordering on it?

Comment: This looks like a *superb* new type of audit!

Comment: @Amaterasu: Past it.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn dang, that is awful - especially given this example.  I am not a member of SO, but my edits on other SE sites are careful - making sure the changes are substantial - when it comes time that I can approve/decline edits - I will take my time to be sure that I am doing a proper job.  I do not envy you mods in having to deal with this rubbish all the time, on the same token, I admire your patience and persistence.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn you can start fighting the problem by banning those three from reviewing for a week, sending them official warning/message explaining why you did that. When the ban period will be over, I believe they will pay much more attention when reviewing.

Comment: see my answer on the other [question here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223141/spam-polishing-audits/223152#223152). Also, @BoltClock'saUnicorn - could you provide some insight on how much effort would require to add a audit review for this kind of horror?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: I think the devs would be in a better position to answer that than I am :)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yep, was hoping you could ask them in the daily private party of the unicorn masonic lobby. :P (naah, actually I mistook you for one of the SE workers).

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: Actually, now that you mention it, I'm just gonna head over and speak to them about my application again... :P

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reviewers responsible have been dealt with. Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

In the future, flag anything you find like this with an "other" flag and ask us to look into the review history for a post. I regularly do that now for spam or vandalism that gets through the system and will take a hard look into the review histories of those approving it.

I know that it's easy to get angry about suggested edits and to believe that the whole system is broken, but remember that the spectacular failures you often see posted on Meta tend to be the worst of the worst. I regularly go back through suggested edit reviews and a significant majority of them clearly did improve the posts. The audits dramatically reduced the number of bad reviewers you see out there, and our tools for hunting down those who evade the audits help to eliminate the worst offenders remaining. However, [things could still be improved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214541/give-new-edit-reviewers-some-audits-to-begin-with/214542#214542), and we really do appreciate people pointing out obvious review failures like this.

Comment: Also, for the record, I'd like to personally thank the three reviewers here: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4172441