# Add a way to warn editors to do more substantial edits

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review

This feature concern [sites with edits review.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237011/227881)

I have been reviewing edits on SO for a little while now, not long as I got 2k rep about a month or so.

Already I see plenty of bad edits... but sometime I see edits that are missing a few things by the same user, over and over.

I tried to tell one that was on a edit roll to make better edits using a comment @username. He stopped after my comment but saw him at it again today with edits that are near good (didn't remove thanks, missed a few spelling errors or formatted things that didn't need to since it wasn't adding to the question/answer).

Other users make formatting changes but nothing else. These changes are good, they make the answer/question more readable but they haven't took the time to actually edit all the other things (remove thanks, spelling, etc).

I'll like to have a more formal way, other than a comment, similar to this [flag reviewer proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223947/227881), that would send them a message in their inbox with a link (all we got at the moment is the [review privilege help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)) telling them that a reviewer(s) saw their edits and that they should take more time to edit the question/answer in the future.

Maybe this shouldn't be left in the hands of 2k+ users, maybe in the 10k tools but that leave reviewers like me that want to warn editors that they should do a better job either trying to do it with comments or flag one of their post and take moderator's time to check their edits (which I do once I see a few near-good edits from the same user).

Another option would be to send that message when 10, for example, of their suggested edits received 2 reject votes while still being approved... I'm not certain there's a metric that could do a good job at detecting editors that could use to be hinted that their edits just need a little more work to be of great value.

After a while, I'm rejecting their edits but there's [enough people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155561/the-robo-approvers-are-killing-my-will-to-review-edits?rq=1) that approve about anything that the message (rejection) won't pass.

Improving their edits over and over doesn't help the editor to make a better edit in the future. It wastes reviewers time more than needed.

Comment: I thought that's what the improve button was for.

Comment: When the same user forgets the same thing over and over, I rather reject the edit than have to improve their edit all the time. Some reviewer will just accept without improving, which doesn't help

Comment: Why? In your examples, the edits are actual improvements, just incomplete. We're all volunteers, and most are not grammar and spelling experts. Incremental improvements are good.

Comment: Some are, some aren't but that's why a feature like this would help, since the editor would understand they are making a ok job but they could be doing a better one.