# Ability to vote for closure from within Review Queue

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, vote-to-close

Just doing a bit of reviewing and came across [this suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4235410). I voted for rejection based on "Too Minor" (a slight rewording of the question). But the question in question was asking for an offsite resource. As such I navigated back to the review, opened the question in a new tab, and issued a close vote.

This is quite a long winded process - is there a way to issue close votes from within the review queue?

If not is it possible for this functionality to be added or is there prior reasoning for this not being a feature?

Comment: Having to close the question is not a regular occurance, is it? Just command-click `link` text to open the post in a new tab, vote to close there. The review queue focuses on the answer post, no need to complicate the UI for this.

Comment: Regular enough that I saw fit to ask about it here :) It tends to be people adding tags or minor things to poor questions which really should be flagged or voted for closure.

Comment: Related (and shameless plug): [Spam-polishing audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/223141/223030)

Comment: @michaelb958 So shameless but so right. Seemed a shame to upvote a post that had 42 votes... never mind.

Answer (score 5):

Finding edits to crap questions is very common. The rep-farmers of the edit plantation frequently rearrange the deck chairs. So the edit queue is, in fact, a great place to find things that need to be closed, and it would be a good idea to do what the OP suggests and facilitate that.