# Should the age or activity of a question be a determining factor when accepting or rejecting an edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Another user recently told me that he rejects minor edits (such as adding syntax highlighting to a post) if they were the only thing present in the edit. The same user said he accepts these edits for posts that are at the top of the Active Questions list.

This leads me to my question: Does the age or activity of a post play a factor when deciding to accept or reject an edit on said post?

Comment: Some sites' users are hesitant to disrupt the order of the active questions list, and discourage non-essential edits more for that reason, even when they correct mistakes like spelling/grammar/punctuation and add useful tags. Seems silly to me, but there may be reasons to care about the active questions list that I'm not as sensitive to. Moderators and high-rep users may feel some personal obligation to keep up with everything that's happening, and this would make it a little more difficult. Many also seem to find minor (but complete!) edits annoying, which I've never really understood...

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful with this.

Edits bump posts back to the top of the front page, regardless of their age, which can be disruptive if it's a post from four years ago. Some people don't like to approve edits that disrupt the order of the Active Questions list since they unnecessarily draw attention to a post that had fallen by the wayside ages ago.

In theory, all *complete* edits should be accepted regardless of their age, but you should be suspicious of edits from new users on old posts because they could be spam.

Essentially, no: treat them as you would any other edit (**especially** when it comes to completeness, as you mentioned), but be aware that some people aren't going to like new edits to old posts because they are often considered unnecessary. (I'd contest that by saying that, if the editor found it, it must still be relevant, so what's the harm in allowing an edit that makes it better/clearer for future viewers? With the amount of activity on most sites, it won't stay on the Active Questions list for long, anyway.)

Comment: Can you expand on what it means to be "complete"? I gave "adding syntax highlighting to a post that lacked it" as an example. Would that be considered complete?

Comment: @Rainbolt I consider "complete" to mean that *all issues* were fixed with a post. There's eventually a line, which is what the minimum character limit is for, but if syntax highlighting is the only issue with a post and it truly makes it better, that's a sensible edit. However, if there are grammar/formatting issues all over the place and the only thing the editor fixes is the syntax highlighting, that's too minor.

Comment: High reputation users are not subject to the character limit. I'm also not certain that syntax highlighting makes a post "better". Users I have talked to can't seem to agree on this matter, which is why I posted this question. I like consensus, because an inconsistent community seems more hostile to newbies, but I understand that some matters are just up to the individual.

Comment: @Rainbolt I know: I assumed you were referring to completeness in regard to suggested edits (i.e. sub-2000 rep). Syntax highlighting is questionable, but if, for example, multiple languages are used in a single post, it's certainly necessary to explicitly define each one. That'd have to be case-by-case, in my opinion.

Answer (score -2):

**Yes**, last activity of a post is a factor in my opinion. Generally speaking, if I see edit made on old post that wasn't otherwise bumped, I will approve only if it's a major edit.

Now the tricky part, what I consider *old post* and *major edit*?

**Old post**: no formula, but somewhere around half a year without activity.

**Major edit**: no formula, so some examples are due.

1. Changing bunch of "i" to "I": minor. Reject on spot.
2. Code formatting: usually too minor in old posts, unless it's lots of code.
3. Fixing grammar: depends on severity of original grammar, sometimes justifies approving even in old posts.

Comment: This is all quite subjective, but I'm not sure about that "i" to "I" = reject on spot. If that's the *only* part of the edit, then sure: too minor, but usually, if there are lowercase "I"s, there are many, many other grammatical/capitalization issues with the post that could also be fixed. I think grammar fixes (if they pass a certain threshold: say, 30 characters) are useful in old posts because, if an editor ends up coming across them, it's likely because they solve an issue, which means that others could find them if they run into the same issue, and grammar fixes/formatting go a long way.

Comment: @AstroCB if there are more grammar mistakes being fixed, it jumps to case #3.

Comment: True; I guess my issue is with the wording, but I agree that if i -> I is the only change, it's too minor.

Comment: Now, this is quite an old post, I have recently joined the reviewing thing, and I also find it confusing, one user send a bunch of edit rewriting xaml to XAML and silverlight to Silverlight (which is in my opinion not enough, especially since the posts in question are 6 years old). Is there a page that says: so you hit the big 2k, what's new?

Comment: @Icepickle no such page at the moment. There is a [pending feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209265/take-the-review-tour) to add such a guide, and I found [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217060/pedantic-edit-yes-no-approve-reject) which is quite relevant to your case. I would reject those edits by the way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, it's a pitty it's a 2 year old feature request, but I upvoted it anyhow :D The suggested discussion also helps, I even learned a new word :D

Comment: @Icepickle cheers, glad I could help. Let me guess... "pedantic"? ;)