# Very old question in the Close Votes review queue

Tags: bug, closed-questions, review-audits

I came upon this close votes review just now: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/3936937

But as it turns out, this question was closed, *and* deleted, two weeks ago. Then why would it show up in the close votes queue now?

Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you try to act on it? It probably was an audit.

Comment: Oh... I failed then. I thought it was real!

Comment: Yeah, that's the intent :)

Comment: Are they supposed to look real? Hm. It looked better than the edit review audits; those don't look real at all. (I don't even have to read those, the abundance of green to the right and no red to the left is clear enough.)

Comment: I disagree with the sentiment that this is a duplicate of "What are audits". 1) I know what audits are, 2) I didn't know that this was one, and 3) the answer "This was an audit" was OK for me, and it does not occur on the other question, so it would have left me wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can confirm this was a review audit. The page you link to now says:

> **Review audit passed** 12 mins ago:
>   *(Username redacted)* reviewed this 12 mins ago:
>   **Close**

Review audits are indeed supposed to look as "real" as possible. We don't want the review drones to be able to identify them on sight.

For more information, see [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks for the confirmation.