# Does passing a review audit decrease the chance of a ban?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits, review-suspension

What I mean to ask is, there are some test reviews too. Which are designed to check whether the user is paying attention or not. After the user has done those reviews, they tell him whether he was correct or was wrong!

Users get banned if they fail too many test reviews.

So, I wanted to ask, whether passing these test reviews counts in minimizing the chances to get banned or not?

Comment: They're called "review audits". I changed that in your title. (As you probably know, you can roll back my edit if you disagree with it).

Comment: No no, that's perfect! :-) Instead of rolling back, I must thank you for correcting me brother! :)

Comment: I dont think passing matters much because you get banned for failing X amount within certain time/amount of reviews.

Comment: Oh, so there is a condition to `fail_these_much_reviews/days_taken_to_fail` .. something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the review audits FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/187824):

> If a user passes the test, nothing happens and they continue reviewing. In some review tasks, they are informed that they passed and thanked for their time and feedback.

So passing the audits doesn't decrease the chance of a ban.