# Automatically remove audits failed often

Tags: feature-request, review, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

A lot of the proposed solutions to bad review audits require extra work, are too ambiguous, don't work in certain review types, or are impossible to implement at scale.

I have a solution I believe should fill those holes reasonably well.

For argument, let's assume:

- **20%** of all review audits are failed
- The *good* review audits are failed closer to **10%** of the time
- *Bad* audits are less common than good audits, but are failed substantially more. Probably close to **50%**.

A lot can be gleaned from this information. Namely, audit quality. Over a certain threshold, like **30%**, it's probably a bad audit, or at least "bad enough."

I propose removing the post from the audit pool and reversing any failed audits when failure exceeds that threshold (and raw number of reviews is large enough to reduce noise). It *might* be beneficial to also consider the experience of the reviewers in determining their weight in this calculation.

There may be a SEDE query that could help to justify this feature, but it feels intuitive enough without.

---

This on its own will do nothing to address complaints, since it's all behind the scenes. What could help address complaints might be changing the **Stop!** text to mention the automated review of audits, so users are encouraged to forge ahead knowing there may be redemption for their perceived transgression.

Comment: We don't like to assume things. I've seen plenty of *very good* audits that have been failed a lot simply because the reviewers actually sucked at reviewing. Just because people are failing it doesn't mean we should stop using it. It could very well be a shining example of an audit that we *should* be using. You're basically saying that audits should almost always be freshly chosen, which only increases the chances of getting a bad audit.

Comment: Would my sentence about considering reviewer experience in the calculation alleviate that concern, or still not quite?

Comment: Call it the Stack Exchange Semi-Intelligent [Watcher](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) [Watcher](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) [Watcher](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226771/automatically-remove-audits-failed-often)™.

Comment: Considering your entire question revolves around a bunch of made-up percentages, nothing short of *actual statistics* will alleviate my concerns.

Comment: @animuson: Although, given actual, tweakable stats, the concept does seem sound.  We do this already with the StackExchange MegaNuclear QuestionQuality Mashinator™, and the Stack Exchange IsoLinear AskerBanninator™.

Comment: Given the very large number of posts that are audit candidates, I'd actually be surprised if more than a handful had been used as audits more than one or two times. I don't know that we'd be able to extract any kind of meaningful statistics from individual audit cases.