# Which sites currently have review-audits?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

Some sites have [review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/168244), and some don't. Which ones currently do and what is the criteria for activating this feature?

Comment: You'll know they're enabled on a site if you fail one. ;)

Comment: @Laura But seriously, the [FAQ on audits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/) should  mention which sites they are on. Right now it says "StackOverflow only", which is obviously out of date... not to mention inconsistent with branding guidelines.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. The MSE [meta-tag:faq] posts are pretty much entirely community maintained. They're going to be a little out of date. (I don't know offhand a complete list where they're enabled, which is why I didn't post a real answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Rory's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work#comment520523_157121) on [the FAQ you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/246931):

> currently they are active on **Stack Overflow, Super User, Programmers and Server Fault**. –  [Rory](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/176080/rory) Mar 29 '13 at 12:34 [emphasis added; note the timestamp is a year old.]

This answer-in-a-comment seems to omit **Mathematics**, as per [the comment you linked](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4541/how-to-deal-with-robo-reviewers#comment14918_4541), and **Ubuntu** [according to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237011/which-sites-currently-have-review-audits#comment776952_237012) @Thisismuchhealthier. (Thanks!)
<sup>Please feel free to edit in any others as they arise, or comment with some kind of supportive link, and I'll edit it in myself.</sup>

Can't speak to the criteria for implementation, but I'm guessing this is decided internally on a per-site basis, maybe sometimes spurred on by feature requests from users (e.g., [Drupal has one going](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2952)).

Comment: They are also active on [math.se], [as far as I know](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4541/how-to-deal-with-robo-reviewers#comment14918_4541).

Comment: @Werner Correct, I get them all the time. [This FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/259867) needs an update. Here is the [filter](http://stackexchange.com/filters/141664/review-audits?sort=active) for `review-audits` tag covering all meta sites. I found [Programmers](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6625) and [Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8584) in addition to those already mentioned.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: yup, I don't see any meta-sites other than Programmers in that filtered search's list of results except [Drupal, which is requesting review audits be implemented](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2952).

Comment: I'm pretty sure these six are all: SO, SF, SU, Math, Programmers, Ubuntu. My search for "audit" on the metas of other large sites turned up nothing. cc: @Werner

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: I updated the FAQ post knowing that it was on [so], but wasn't sure about other sites. Then I posted this question to collect that information.

Comment: @Werner Okay. Now I edited these six in. By the way, I disagree with faq-proposed, the existing FAQ post on audits logically collects the information in one place.