# How does a site initiate a request for having review audits?

Tags: support, review-audits, per-site-meta

This is a follow-up question to [Which sites currently have review-audits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237011/168244)

Not every site has review audits active. So, how does a site go about requesting to have review audits initiated? Is there any formal procedure for this like polling on the child-meta?

Comment: As mentioned there, [that's what Drupal is doing](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2952)...though I'm not saying that formalizes it as the established procedure. (Er...does it?) I see it has some support from the Drupal mod(s).

Answer (score 6):

The natural way is to bring it up for discussion on the site's meta. For example, on Math this  was  brought up on August 23, 2013: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10740/ and implemented a week later.

Perhaps the reason that the Drupal discussion [Please introduce review audits on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2952) has not led to any action yet is that the level of support expressed there is not that high. (Or maybe Drupal moderators forgot to bring the topic to attention of Community Team, I would not know.)

Comment: Our maybe the Team also considers the level of activity in the queue, and the number of approved edits that are subsequently rolled back.

Comment: The number of votes on the Meta.DA post are just about as high as they would go, given the level of participation there.  We didn't explicitly ping the CM team, though.

Comment: @MPD It's not too late to do this. CMs monitor  the metas, but with posts like these one has to wait until the discussion reaches some plateau... and they would not necessarily know when that happens.