# Have covert review audits been secretly rolled-out on some sites?

Tags: discussion, support, review, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

Recently, in the last few weeks I've noticed a shift, reviews turning-up particularly in the reopen queue which show no indication of having been edited to be any more on-topic. (Of course, they've had upvoted answers and so have not been roomba-ed).

Most recent post: [on Sci-Fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121097/is-there-a-complete-list-of-jk-rowlings-harry-potter-tweets). Not able to link to the review directly, but it's [the most recent one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/history) I performed there.

This is something to be expected occasionally, as newly privileged members with a reopen vote stretch their muscles, but it's happened more and more frequently on a couple of sites I review on: Worldbuilding, Sci-Fi & Fantasy.

I say covert because the pop-up wasn't the familiar (to frequently audited reviewers):

> #### Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. This post
> has already been removed, but thanks for taking time to leave feedback for the
> author.

But rather, a simple:

> This post is no longer eligible for review.

**Question:**

Are there covert review-audits being tested, or is it some random convergence of events - some over-enthusiastic new reopen voters plus a dodgy mouse-button provoking an odd message?

**Expected response:**

If there are new review audits, tell us either here or perhaps update the community wiki in this post:
[Which sites currently have review-audits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237011/which-sites-currently-have-review-audits)

Comment: Could you provide the link to the reviews? "This post is no longer eligible for review" is expected if any actions done by other users (either from inside the review or outside/directly on the post) have been done and make further review moot.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. I've linked to the review history and the post. Could it as you seem to hint, be that others got there and finished the review before I'd gotten to that point?

Comment: It could be. According to [the timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/121097/timeline), [this is the review](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/192972) and user "Jiminy Cricket." chose the last "leave closed" at 01:58:26Z, so if you opened the review before that but submitted the action after that, then the review has already completed.

Comment: Ah. The timeline seems to indicate it might have been a double-click issue, maybe an out-of-sync thing with my browser and the server that deals with such things. I'll put it down to "molehill, not mountain" anyhow. Thanks for your help. @MetaAndrewT.

Comment: Note that the system allows a 15-minute grace period during which users are allowed to submit reviews even after they're completed, so as to ensure everyone reviewing gets credit toward badges even if the review gets completed in the meantime. In your case, it's likely that more than 15 minutes passed since the review completed before you submitted.

Comment: Seems like a race condition at best, not a covert review audit.

Comment: @Mast Oddly, it seems to have not realy happened again after posting this. Race-condition, or dodgy mouse - perhaps. I've a different mouse now, so who knows.