# Filter by tag in Close Votes review gives question without that tag

Tags: bug, review, vote-to-close, review-audits

I was reviewing [python](/questions/tagged/python) Close Votes in the review queues.

When I pressed 'Next' in the review page, it gives me a question which is not related to [python](/questions/tagged/python).

Check below screenshot [image: filter in review is not working]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That means that it is a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/229438). The audit system does not look at your filter, hence you can get a question that's not tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python).

Comment: I don't know about `review audit`, but yes its giving me question which are not tagged by [tag:python]

Comment: @Lafada Take a look at the question I linked. A review audit is a test to see whether you are paying attention.

Comment: I read `review audit`, I want to know that, if I got message **You Passed** test, then also `review audit` will not look for filter?

Comment: @Lafada The review audit system does not look at your filter; it does not matter when.