# User rejected edit suggestions is changed

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I dont't know if it is a bug because I don't know how the review section works.

But waiting for my suggested edit being reviewed I saw the first reviewer with **392** *suggested edits approved* and **92** *suggested edits rejected* but now that the second reviewer accepted my suggested edit, the first user now have **1** rejected suggested edits...

I know that the number can grow but it seems strange to me that it can decrease...

How is it possible?

My suggested edit was approved but still the user has **1** *suggested edit rejected*.

Comment: Do you have a link to the review item?

Comment: Yes, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7401973

Comment: Which reviewer was it? They both have 1 now.

Comment: Sorry, it is the first in the queue, I don't know if I can link him

Comment: Now it is saying he has 0 to me... http://stackoverflow.com/users/169895/berkay

Comment: Sorry again, I meant http://stackoverflow.com/users/152786/smathy

Comment: in his `Actions` section on SO there are more than one rejected edits