# Are review queues curated for the reviewer?

Tags: support, review

I notice that I get a lot of Python/pandas related suggested edits when I'm in the review queue.  Is it my imagination that I'm getting a higher share of Python/pandas posts?  Or are the queues curated to better align the reviewers expertise with the posts being reviewed?

[This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/326787) doesn't address this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorta...

[As Arulkumar notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289781/are-review-queues-curated-for-the-reviewer/289783#289783), it's possible to explicitly filter by tags. But even if you *don't* do that, the system will try to pick a task based on your preferences - preferring to assign tasks that are associated with your favorite tags and avoiding those in your ignored tags.

Now, this isn't always possible; it doesn't look at every task in the queue, preferring to assign posts from among the thousand most recently added tasks - so the utility for very large queues (Close...) is limited. And it doesn't happen for all review queues - Triage straight-up ignores tag preferences (and also doesn't let you filter by tags). Also, wildcard support is still marked as "TODO", so if your tag preferences depend on wildcards you're not gonna see an effect. Finally, if all of the available tasks have your ignored tags or none of them have your favorite tags, the routine just gives up and you get whatever is there.

But for a queue that often has between a few dozen and a few hundred tasks in it, then **yes**: the system will attempt to play match-maker and put you in front of posts that you have some hope of knowing something about.

Comment: Wait, [it does now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254145/suggest-to-me-what-tag-filtering-i-should-use-in-review-next)

Comment: This has been in place since 2012. See caveats.

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure, you are not added the **python** and **pandas** tags in your Suggested Edits review queue filter, like the below:

> [image: Suggested Edits with tags specific]

When you were added the tags in the filter, you only receiving the suggested edits that are containing the **python** and **pandas** tags.

Comment: I had no idea that was there... I checked and no, I do not.  That said, now knowing this is here, it makes it highly unlikely that there is additional curation occurring.