# Providing additional information about review audits

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just hit my first review audit on SuperUser.  I actually saw through the audit & thought it was a bug, and so tried to report it as a bug by flagging for moderator attention.  Instead, I was hit with a [failed audit](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/377401) because it was, in fact, a high-quality answer and I was supposed to review it as such.

Having little familiarity with audits, I was [rather upset](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9347/failed-audit-trying-to-report-apparent-bug-in-review-queue/9348) -- "What consequences am I facing from having failed this audit?!?"  Canadian Luke quite kindly and promptly walked me back from the ledge, saying that one or two failed audits was nothing to worry about, but it prompted me to look around for more information about audits.  I was able to find almost nothing: audits aren't mentioned in the [SU site tour](https://superuser.com/tour) (which is sensible; audits are for already-committed users, not new joiners), and searching the SU help pages for 'audit' currently yields [zero hits](https://superuser.com/help/search?q=audit).  In particular, the structure of the chain of consequences for failed audits is nowhere spelled out, that I can find.

**Suggestions:**

1. <strike>Add a boilerplate help page about audits</strike> -- Per Tim's comment, this has [already been done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work).
2. Code in a small popup window when an account gains reviewing privileges that includes a link to the audit page

   1. If there already is such a pop-up, then just add a link to the audit info
3. In the post-audit info box, add a 'more information about audits' link to the info page

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: @Tim Great! Sounds like #1 is already taken care of. What about #2 and/or #3?