# Warn reviewers about audits on the privileges page?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

When I first gained 500 reputation and did some reviewing, I came across a question that was your typical new-user spam.

I clicked on the link to it and found that it was closed. Not wanting to clutter queues with an issue that had already been resolved - even unsure of what would happen if I flagged a closed question - I clicked on 'No Action Needed'. Then I got the infamous 'audit failed' message.

Surely there should be a warning that some reviews are audits and to always review as you believe you should, even if there seems to be a bug? This warning would be on the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) for accessing review queues.

**Related: [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256419/providing-additional-information-about-review-audits)**.

Answer (score 5):

I like this idea.

Many users, including myself, have been tripped up by this at first. Once we know about it fine, but we shouldn't be able to be "tripped up" by our *paying attention* and *choosing a logical outcome*, in that:

"Post is deleted - job done" ok job done so "no action needed".

The audit is to catch out users who are *not* paying attention or do make bad decisions. It should not be a fail and penalise the very users who *are already doing* what the audit is there to ensure is being done.

### That said

If you are paying attention, then it is only one fail, and from then on whenever you see a post which is already deleted then you know it's an audit.

The audit system is not supposed to be a complex system which tackles all possible angles. It's just a basic setup designed to "catch the worst most of the time". So we have to have *some* concern over what information we release about audits, as there are simple things users can do "quickly" to avoid audit failures.