# Review audits on a beta site

Tags: discussion, review-audits, beta-sites

I saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work/157172#157172) earlier, saying that there were only review audits on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, Programmers, Ask Ubuntu, and Mathematics.

However, I got a [review audit](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/10590) on a beta site yesterday in the Low Quality Posts review queue.

I searched, but didn't find any post regarding whether all sites now have review audits. Do they now?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I believe it's this one: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/10590

Comment: Obviously your experience says that audits are on all sites and not just beta, so the post you linked is outdated.

Comment: @psubsee I just wanted to make sure, since I actually pointed someone to that post recently.