# How are audit questions decided

Tags: discussion, review-audits

So I took my first cautious peek into the review queue and failed an audit, I was presented with an answer that I down voted.

I didn't think the answer I was presented with was specific enough in relation to the question asked, or gave any direct answers. I've not posted the link to the question/answer because I'm not asking if others believe that is right or wrong.

What I'm interested in knowing is how questions make it into an audit review? Is it automated or does someone actually nominate/vote/assign questions into the review queue?

EDIT:

I reviewed the suggested previous question [What are review tests (audits) and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work)
It only seems to imply that providing an answer has many upvotes it can qualify. I'm asking if that is the only qualifying criteria?

Comment: Yes it's 100% automatic  and the criteria is included in the faq.