# Pre-generate Review audits to avoid the lag?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits

When reviewing on Suggested Edits:

- Normal suggested edits are displayed instantly.
- Review audits take 2 seconds to load (and that's not because of my ISP).

So whenever I see the loading animation and have to wait a bit, I know before even looking at the changes that I can immediately reject the suggested edit.

Now, to quote [this community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) <sup><sub>([paragraph added anonymously less than a year ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/53392))</sub></sup>:

> There are many ways to identify audits (e.g. click to see the post itself, the user, the vote count, etc.). Almost all of these ways involve having to further investigate the post. By this time, you've already carefully reviewed the post, which is the intent of the queues.

This let us understand that the 2 seconds lag is *breaking* the game: it allows detection of the audit without careful review of the post, without further investigation.

My feature-request is to have Review audits being served *as fast as* real suggested edits. To achieve that, you could maybe pre-generate audits?

Comment: Performance tuning is hard. Maybe it is easier to postpone normal suggested edits tasks with 2 seconds ...

Comment: ... which would also annoy robo-reviewers more.

Comment: I (or rather, Ano) adapted that text from a similar question on MSO. This particular situation was already reported there, but was closed as a dupe of that post. I don't think it's a dupe, because this is one of those cases where one can tell it's an audit without any sort of review.

Comment: But as I edited there a few months ago, if you do spot a user who is approving everything but somehow rejecting only the audits, feel free to flag one of their posts so a mod can manually ban them.

Comment: similar feature request at MSO: [Foreshadowing of suggested edit audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/372173/839601)