# Wrong dates in comments in Triage review

Tags: support, comments, review, dates, triage

I see wrong dates for comments in the Triage review queue. The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20008343) is asked 29 minutes ago (today), but the comments are dated 24 May.

> [image: Please check the attached image.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20008343

Answer (score 1):

You have a good pair of eyes. The 'bug' here isn't a bug. [It is a review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20008343), and you passed:

> Review audit passed 35 secs ago:

I guess the system updates some information on the post in order to hide it is a review audit. In this case, it worked as designed: you paid attention, you pass.

See [the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50501361/993547) where the dates are more realistic.

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't asked 29 minutes ago, it's in fact a much older question used as a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/295232). Those will appear as new questions. The comments actually give away that it's a review audit; I've posted a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311233/295232) for the comments to be re-dated as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a review audit. As such, it displays a fake timestamp to prevent people from identifying it as a review audit immediately.

By looking through the question's comments, you've signified that you're paying attention to posts, and aren't a mindless robo-reviewer.