# Comments shown in review audits should be re-dated

Tags: feature-request, comments, review-audits, dates

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/311229/295232), where [this review audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/20008343) shows the question as posted as a few minutes ago, while the comments are much older (May 24th). This makes it very easy to see it's a review audit.

If the *post* can be re-dated to make it look recent, it's a small step to also shift the dates on the comments. This affects most review queues; IIRC only the Suggested Edits review queue doesn't show them.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a review audit is to see if a user pays attention. You can make all sorts of changes to make it less obvious it is a review audit, but what does it actually matter? If you want to know it is a review audit, you can just simply click the question link and you will know for sure. A robo-reviewer won't do all that.

I am not against your feature request, I just think we could spent time better on something that helps the community more.

Comment: How do we detect users who robo-review but somehow pass the audits? In other words, users who have discovered a system loophole, or using a user script that unmasks audits?

Comment: We don't I guess. They will eventually be caught by humans that disagree with their decision. And maybe there are some more mod tools that list users often disagreeing with the majority.