# Test question in review queues does not change comment date correctly

Tags: bug, comments, review

While reviewing questions in the review queue, sometimes StackOverflow will change the question dates and hide votes to test if the reviewer is paying attention or not.

While the date of the question is hidden, the date of comments remains the same as the original. So the reviewer can easily spot the mismatch and determine that it is a Test question.

Either we should change the comment date also or hide the comments completely.

In the screenshot, as you can see that question was asked a few mins ago but comments are 10 days old.

[image]

Comment: Discussed in https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311233/comments-shown-in-review-audits-should-be-re-dated also. Will accept as duplicate.

Comment: Yup, that's my intended duplicate. I *knew* I asked about it before, the search just didn't let me find it :(