# Why are comments shown in this audit, but I cannot click the two additional comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits

I just passed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21102142).

Why is there one comment shown (which basically gives you a hint, that this is possibly spam)?

Clicking the additional comments won't work and tells you, and this is an audit. (Besides the red background, the audit looked exactly the same, including comments). Shouldn't the comments be hidden?

[image]

Comment: Also note that the spam is extremely subtle and this post should probably not be an audit - audits are supposed to be *extremely obvious* and designed to catch robo-reviewers off-guard. You should file a request on the per-site meta requesting the spam flags be cleared (moderators do this to remove bad audits from review).

Comment: Submitted a flag: _helpful_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments could be hidden to make this audit *slightly* more difficult, but this is not necessary. Review audits aren't meant to be very difficult, but are instead, as @SonictheInclusiveWerehog said, meant to catch bot reviewers.

If you want more information, read the paragraph titled "A review is obviously an audit. Should I report it?" in the answer to this [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) for a full discussion.