# Reopen Votes review audits use old JS confirm dialog instead of new Stacks prompt, making them too easy to identify

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits

If I vote to reopen a question that appeared on the Reopen Votes queue and it turns out that it is an audit, I get this JS browser confirmation dialog:

[image]

But if it is not an audit, then I get this Stacks design popup:

[image]

This looks silly. The same type of confirmation should be used. Otherwise, the audits become really easy to spot.

Comment: Previously, the former dialog was how actual reopen votes (not only review, but on questions themselves also) would be handled; this was changed a couple months ago to the latter, but apparently audits were overlooked.

Comment: I think I've seen that dialog in the past few weeks, but received no [notification of failure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/282094); so it comes out for passers and failers.

Comment: What is a *"Stacks prompt"*? There is an image of it, but what is its significance, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

This will be fixed in the next prod build. Thanks for the report!