# What happens when a review is reviewed after the post gets edited?

Tags: support, review, edits, flags

I don't think I would have made [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25782776) review. Otherwise it was an unintentional mistake which earned me a frustrating review ban. I am also not able to view the deleted post and hence look at its edit history.

It made me wonder if the post was completely edited after my review, which got my review flagged. Even if not, I would like to know what happens in this case?

Does the reviewer who reviews the reviews get a notice if the post gets edited after the review?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's spam. It doesn't [require editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295674/4751173), it requires [flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/295232). The post was never edited (I have 10k on Stack Overflow and can see the post's history).

> Does the reviewer who reviews the reviews get a notice if the post gets edited after the review?

Sorry, I misunderstood that. In this case, it's an automatic test (a ['review audit'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157121/295232)), which is indicated as follows: **Review audit failed Apr 5 at 19:07:**
♦ moderators can hand out manual bans, but they will only do so if they see a bad *pattern*, and they will take into account that a post was edited after being reviewed. Still, they are humans and can make mistakes; if you believe you have been banned in error, you can appeal on Meta (but do it on [Stack Overflow's own Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), not here).

Comment: Thank you, I know that. Maybe I was not careful, but what's the answer to the main question?

Comment: I see, but I was not asking if I would get a notification. I am asking if the reviewer(moderator or whoever) who reviews a review (made before that post got edited to an entirely different thing) would get a notice. If there is no way to mark it, someone might earn an unwarranted review ban imho.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that. Too many 'review's in one sentence and too few coffee ...

Comment: No problem. You are the only one who has answered my questions on this site so far :P