# Why was this question audited ~10 times over 1 month as "First questions"?

Tags: support, questions, review-audits

https://superuser.com/posts/1708371/timeline:

[image]

Why was this question audited ~10 times over 1 month as "First questions"? The OP has ~500 questions, ~18k rep and no bans on this SE. The  question has 12 upvotes and no downvotes.

Comment: Why does the OP's stats matter? Audits are chosen to be "known good" or "known bad" examples to make sure people are paying attention. And they are repeatedly used for up to a month once selected. Do you maybe not understand what [audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work) means? It doesn't mean the question was actually reviewed as a first question.

Comment: @animuson I thought first question was meant for first question(s). You're welcome to post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt There are two types of review entries that can show up in a timeline. If you look further down, you'll see a close review which is marked as "review" where a close vote actually pushed the question into that review queue. Ones labeled as "audit" were the question being selected as an audit example (in this case, a known good question based on its score).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt FYI, I asked a quite similar question earlier at [Some posts from users who are not "new" users (e.g., one with over 620 answers & about 18,000 rep.) ending up in the First Posts queue](/q/343810), with this one being related to multiple "audit" of type "first post" although this question was the OP's 23rd one.

Comment: @animuson got it, thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure neither known-good nor known-bad audits take poster rep into consideration. In any case, it would be nearly impossible to find a very low rep user's post that has the upvotes needed to show the system that the post is quality and should be used as a known-good audit.

Comment: @Laurel thanks, I confused reviews with audits.