Potential flow / giveaway: Review-audits seems to take longer to appear
When doing some late answers reviews on Stack Overflow, it seemed to me that a question took longer to appear the the previous ones: it was a review-audit.
This "feeling" caught me several times: maybe I was "lucky", but maybe a bot could use some latency delta between real and audit reviews...
Since https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/1573298 mentions that

if you find something in the review audit system that makes audits extremely obvious [...], feel free to report that flaw

I wanted to share this feeling I had (and couldn't add a comment to that answer).
Thus this "question" / experience sharing:

Could there be a reason why review audits may take longer to load, and/or
is there a random delay before questions appear (and I've been lucky), and/or
am I seeing non-existent patterns (& making a fool of myself)?


This has been reported on Meta Stack Overflow already, e.g. here - I'd agree that it's probably a bug.

Reported for suggested edits here.

Yeah. Whenever an edit is taking abnormally long to load, I will zoom in to the review options, and immediately click Reject and edit without even looking at the edit. Always an audit.
