# Mechanism to provide feedback to reviewers who rubber stamp?

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits, review-abuse, community-standards

During a recent `Review Suggested Edits` session, I came across a reviewer who is clearly rubber stamping edits (`Approved 550 edit suggestions and rejected 7`), and who had missed an [obvious case of vandalism](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1116994) by an anonymous miscreant.

How about considering mechanisms, which:

- Give feedback to reviewers that their reject rate lies outside a
  normal range of the larger community (e.g. outside of 2 sigma)
- Introduce some kind of penalty for repeat rubberstamping (e.g. revoking review rights and / or revocation of review badges?)

Comment: [Welcome to the club](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-fake-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything)

Comment: +1. Generally, if I find such robo-reviewer, I comment on their older post and request them to not review like a robot. I planned to add a feature-request about giving feedback to other reviewer. Thanks.

Comment: you have to worry that some people might rather *skip* than *reject*, which results in a large accept rate that's completely legitimate

Comment: @Jeff - point taken, but I'm a bit old fashioned, and believe that there should always be consequence for bad behaviour. IMO skipping anything which should be rejected could also be regarded as dereliction of duty?

Comment: meh, i disagree... skipping should not be a punishable offense. aren't the audits supposed to take care of this problem?

Comment: @Jeff I'm not sure I follow - does choosing "skip" instead of "accept" accept an edit?

Comment: @Pekka He means if they see 20 good edits and 10 bad ones, they'll accept the 20 and skip the 10 (I assume because they feel bad rejecting? I'm not sure why) and have a 100% accept rate

Comment: @Michael ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: [honeypot items](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156822/165773) for robo-approvers are easy to do: _take a reasonably good post, make a suggestion to wrap it into senseless "Hi" and "Thanks", add an absurd edit comment like "improved formatting" and voila_. Similar items with unambiguously good suggestions should be there, too, in order to avoid converting robo-approvers into robo-rejectors.  **[Handful reviews proven fake => two weeks review suspension](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XJWwR.png "just like it's done to those giving too much rejected edits")**

Comment: ...making _unambiguously good_ honeypot item isn't a rocket science either: take a reasonably recent post with hi-thanks and missing code formatting; suggest to remove hi-thanks and format the code with comment like _"1) code formatting 2) personal stuff removed"_

Comment: i dont know why this [fahim-parkar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1066828/fahim-parkar) user approve ....

Comment: @hims056 you mean, "please don't approve..." comments like **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067595/core-image-filter-each-time-new-resulting-image#comment18169581_13067595), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql/12364314#comment18077529_12364314) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10271417/android-alarmmanager-multiple-alarms-one-overwrites-the-other/10271488#comment18077524_10271488)**? I really like it! While SE team is hanging there in analysis paralysis, this seems to be the best **community can do**

Comment: @gnat - Yes. And now I also include another sentence like *[I will remove this comment after your reply]* So that they don't repine and reply us properly. :)

Comment: @hims056 well I am not sure that _replying_ helps. :( User who _replied_ to [second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364086/how-can-i-achieve-initcap-functionality-in-mysql/12364314#comment18077529_12364314) listed above, still has stats that raised my eyebrows **"approved 438 edit suggestions and rejected 1"**

Comment: @gnat - Yes I know that particular user but we can't handle every people but at least we should try to improve review quality.

Comment: @hims056 how to see edit status ?of others

Comment: @hims056 you mean, we, **as community** should try, right? I stress _community_ since so far it's hard to see how _SE team_ helps here

Comment: @NullPointer - Go to any suggested edit review (which is already reviewed or reviewed by you) [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1116994) and click on (more)

Comment: @gnat - Yes exactly :)

Comment: @gnat you would like to see status of http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1044307 here http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1044307 even not rejected one edit

Comment: The only positive point of those reviewers is that they stop reviewung when they reach 1000 reviews in a queue.

Comment: @NullPointer - OMG! Looks like `Reject` and `Skip` buttons are not visible on that user's browser. **approved 999 edit suggestions and rejected 0**

Comment: @gnat - and everyone else who is part of this conversation. Please refrain from vandalizing other posts and their comment-walls with references to people's approve/reject posts. That doesn't "improve the quality of the site's content" in any way - it merely muddies up what appears on other pages in an effort to penalize or shame someone. I agree that there needs to be a mechanism for noticing rubber-stamping - but that mechanism shouldn't be to turn our comment boards into trolling chat-windows.

Comment: @GamecatisToonKrijthe's prediction has come to pass - the reviewer identified by NullPointer got his gold, and stopped. He has a perfect 1000:0 record as at the time of writing

Comment: @StuartC And it still stands at 1000:0. Alas, I've seen robo reviewers that don't stop at 1000.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of now, there is no *systemic* way to provide feedback like one you ask about. As far as I understand, [SE team is working on this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151587/165773).

Meanwhile, technically there is an option to [politely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#benice) contact reviewers making questionable decisions via comments [as discussed above](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187824/hims056).

As an example, **[here is a comment to reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979932/sorting-two-columns-in-opposite-way#comment18810322_10979932)** mentioned in your question:

> <sub>@FahimParkar Please don't approve [suggested edits like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1116994). If needed, refer to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/165773) for details.</sub>

---

Some more example comments submitted to reviewers who were complained about in [review-abuse](/questions/tagged/review-abuse) meta posts...

- **[Here is a comment to reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891065/css-only-scrollable-table-with-fixed-headers#comment18828493_11891065)** who approved the edit <sup>[*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157591/165773)</sup> consisted in its entirety of adding [solved] to the title:

  > <sub>@TroyAlford Please don't approve [suggested edits like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1126492). If needed, refer to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/165773) for details.</sub>
- **[Here is a comment to reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694584/whats-so-special-about-cardlayout-vs-manual-adding-removal-of-jpanels#comment18810468_10694584)** who approved blatant vandalism from anonymous user:

  > <sub>@WATTOStudios Please don't approve [suggested edits like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/827006). If needed, refer to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/165773) for details.</sub>
- **[Here is a comment to reviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471386/how-to-add-onchange-event-to-dropdown-boxes-of-jquery-datepicker#comment18810515_13471386)** who approved blatantly invalid edit:

  > <sub>Please don't approve [suggested edits like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/823123). If needed, refer to this [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/165773) for details.</sub>

Comment: Your ideas about the honeypot - both false positive and false negative  - are great way to detect and 'sentence' offenders.

Comment: As in my above comment - I don't think this is a particularly appropriate way to keep our community clean. It changes the topic of other postings and muddies what appears when users search for other topics.

Comment: I'd just like to point to 2 legitimate reasons for your comment @gnat, so you can be aware that not everyone is simply rubber-stamping. **1.** Reviewing on a mobile device means that sometimes the wrong button is clicked accidentally - there is no 'undo' button, but thats why there are 3 reviews before anything is accepted. **2.** Also due to mobile devices, it is easier to Approve legitimate posts and Skip incorrect ones, then it is to perform Edits, therefore I have a generally higher accept count compared to my rejects/edits. Please dont be so quick to lump everyone in the same basket!

Comment: I do not think systemic means what you think it means :]

Comment: @Emracool to me, _systemic_ means a way that wouldn't involve personal comments to randomly discovered problematic reviewers

Comment: Ah, I meant by the actual definition. But I think you're right, technically it is an appropriate use of systemic. It just sounded weird to me xD