# Using comments to chat with other OS user and also off-topic

Tags: discussion, comments

```
Update:
```

*Here I have shwon some examples of such a comments but they were already deleted after
I have flagged it*

How can we avoid such a comments?
How can we delete it?

Is it correct?

**Update:**

Moderators have deleted such a comment after I flagged it with

> using comments to chat with other SO users. Off-topic comment

and not  declined it

Comment: Um... What? I don't exactly understand what you're saying...

Comment: What makes you think those comments are something that needs avoiding?

Comment: @Doorknob - why not? Have you look at the links I posted?

Comment: I have. What's wrong with those comments?

Comment: @Pekka웃 - cause I think comments I used to help solve the question asked not for ohter purposes

Comment: The first one is an answer, with one helpful comment, and the second is an activity page (how is that even relevant?)

Comment: Using comments to contact a user over something he's doing on Stack Overflow is generally accepted, I'm sure one could even find statements from the site's founders to that effect. I don't think it's problematic.

Comment: @Doorknob - secone one is activity page to show copy & paste action of this user posting huge number of comments. Maybe it is correct to post comment to communicate with other users - event not with the authors of the posts

Comment: @Mikro There's nothing wrong with copying and pasting comments. There's even a user script for it! http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se (which I use)

Comment: @Pekka웃 - its about site but has in some situation nothing to do with the question and with the answer. It is adressed for example editors of the post

Comment: @Doorknob - my question is not about - are copy & paste comments good or bad

Comment: Then what is it about? I'm still confused

Comment: @Doorknob - about off-topic comments that adressed not to the authors of the post but the editros of the post

Comment: @Mikro Nothing wrong with that. How else would you contact them?

Comment: Until the feature request for [Mechanism to provide feedback to reviewers who rubber stamp?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/187824) is not completed, [this is the correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157423/mechanism-to-provide-feedback-to-reviewers-who-rubber-stamp#comment-454410) way to [educate robo-reviewer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157544/187824).

Comment: @hims056 - that will be the solution to avoid such a comments

Comment: Please do not flag fresh comments designed to educate a user about how to use Stack Overflow just because you think it's against the rules. That's counter-productive and idiotic.

Answer (score 2):

As per literal Stackoverflow policy, comments are used

1. ask for clarification regarding a question or answer.
2. ask poster to add more information/ remove incorrect information

But comments are  normally also used to

1. Help users who are struggling with stackoverflow, like linking to
   code formatting information to help a user struggling with code
   formatting. This also includes letting a poster know that he is doing
   it in the wrong way (which is what the user in question is doing).
2. Post information relative to question/answer (or add links relative
   to question/answer) which does not directly answer the question, but
   helps the user in some other way.

Also it is **acceptable** to copy and paste one's comment across multiple posts, if **it fits those contexts**. Make sure you don't do that with answers though, or at least link to the original if you are doing so.

Comment: so you mean its not off-topic to write a comment with the information for someone who edited this question?

Comment: cause moderators have deleted such a comments after I have flag it as off-topic and not declined my flag

Comment: @MikroDel Moderators deletes comments which are spams, offensive, abusive, too chatty, which doesn't add any useful information to the community. But you can write a comment that helps the OP (and future visitors) and it is allowed. Make sure that your comment is **right** in the context, and is not abusive, harsh and unrelated.

Comment: so that mean if this comment was deleted I have flag it correctly?

Comment: Comment will be deleted if Moderator finds the flat is correct and the comment is not suitable for that site. Of course they can think otherwise and reject your flat.

Comment: @MikroDel Moderation policy will not always be consistent. As you can see, there are quite a few users who have no issues with such comments, and others would probably delete them.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is not a completed mechanism for providing feedback to edit reviewers, so the only way to get in touch with them is to comment on a relevant post to bring their attention to the issue. If you would like to see this done another way, perhaps upvoting this would help:

[Mechanism to provide feedback to reviewers who rubber stamp?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/157423/145951)

In the mean time, commenting is the only real solution we have to curb behavior like this.

The bigger problem to me is that the meta post the guy is linking to from Stack Overflow is Arcade, the gaming site. While the post is clearly on target, the weight of "community consensus" that it carries for SO is dubious. Perhaps we need an equivalent post on MSO.

Comment: If the mechanism is not implemented yet we shouldnt use comments if they are not introduced in SO for this purposes

Comment: Cause the other way - for example in one year such a feature from your post will be here. And we have a lot of comments that will not be automatically deleted

Comment: @Mikro but it's the only way of contacting users at the moment. What alternative do you suggest we use?

Comment: @Pekka웃 is is a wrong way - thats why moderators deleted ALL such a comments I have flagged

Comment: @Pekka웃 - if we have no alternative its not mean we have to use wrong tools. You can for example propose some alternative and vote for it

Comment: @MikroDel fair enough, but as has been pointed out, the tool is not really wrong in this case. It's generally accepted you can use comments for this purpose. If the team think there is a serious problem with this, they may implement an alternative. At the moment, they don't seem to think so either.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - no you cannot - the other way such a comment wouldnt deleted by moderators

Comment: @Pekka웃 - not a once time was my flag for such a comment declined

Comment: @MikroDel it's perfectly acceptable to flag such comments for cleanup after a while, and it's perfectly acceptable for moderators to delete them. However, that doesn't mean it's totally forbidden to use comments for the purpose. What is the problem here anyway? This will be a tiny fraction of all comments, a couple dozen maybe. There's tens, if not hundreds of thousands of other pointless comments out there. Why not concentrate on those instead of this minor issue?

Comment: @Pekka웃 you cannot make it use of comment forbidden. Every one is free to type text he want it comment. But if it is wrong - it is deleted - if not flag is declined

Comment: @Pekka웃 to summarize - we have different opinions. Your opinion has a majority of users who has read this topic I have started. My opinion has some user and moderators.

Comment: @MikroDel You cannot use "my flag wasn't declined" as an argument for unacceptable use of comments. One of the valid reasons to flag comments is that they are **obsolete**. Once you've notified the right user that their specific action needs fixing next time and that user has seen the notification, the comment can be deleted. It is not particularly relevant to anybody else and it's served its purpose. You are welcome to go on flagging these, but please do so after the recipient has been active on the site since posted. Deleting is valid, but it doesn't make the use of the comment system wrong.