# Is failed or passed reviews of honeypot questions viewable in my activity history?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

I was wondering about disabling honeypot questions for users with over 500 flags (or an acceptable number). Surely if a user has got this many of "helpful" flags they have a fairly good grasp of the reviewing and flagging system. However, I can't actually find a list of the honeypot questions I've recieved, and passed or failed. In my memory, I've only failed one (ironically just a few minutes ago).

Another user noted:

> in theory, all the reviews, including failed, as well as passed audits are expected to be logged in your "recent-activity" profile section, in the sub-tab "reviews".

The "in theory" line was added as he was unable to find an example to prove that they are logged, and if I go back to my history I also cannot see the review audit I failed earlier.

So, can review audit questions be added to the review history in your profile, and if it is passed/failed?

Answer (score 3):

Failed/passed reviews are visible in your activity history.

Example:

- [This suggested edit audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1656411) is visible on my [activity history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92837/sathya?tab=activity&sort=reviews)

Comment: Thanks, @Sathya. It seems that the review audits are not flagged up as being audits at all. It also seems that the one I failed recently has not appeared in my activity list, yet.