# Review Audit Honeypot Bug

Tags: bug, review-audits

Related to: [Improving the Quality of Reviews: Project Honeypot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152709/131956)

---

[This has actually happened to me on two separate occassions.]

- While reviewing, I came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2665371) that looked legitimate.
- I noticed a comment from [@Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/102937/robert-harvey), and I wanted to understand the point that he was making.
- Within my Google Chrome browser, I right-clicked on the link and selected 'Open link in new tab.'
- I actually agreed with Robert's comment (that the linked post was related) but also felt that the "honeypot" was a legitimate question.
- But when I returned to the review task, I saw the 'STOP! Look and Listen.' message telling me that I failed the review audit.

A few points:

1. I'm not a robo-editer. I promise. :)
2. This is the second time that this has happened to me. That is, this is the second time that I wanted to know more about the comments that various people had attached to a honeypot, opened a link in a new tab, and returned to the review audit, only to find out that I had FAILED!!!!

Please help.

Comment: I've opened review audits in new tabs many times and never had it auto-fail me while I was viewing the question... I can't imagine why it would record that you voted to close if you didn't actually click the Close button.

Comment: @animuson: I swear - I didn't. And if I could manually trigger a honeypot, I'd be willing to try and reproduce it.

Comment: @animuson: Also - For the record, concerning my specific question, couldn't one reasonably mark this question as a duplicate of the related question that Robert Harvey pointed out? In other words, while the question probably deserves to remain open, if somebody legitimately felt that it was a duplicate of Robert Harvey's linked question, I don't feel like that would be worthy of a failure. [But maybe I'm just contesting this question as a slam-dunk honeypot.]

Comment: Which link did you right-click? The "link" link in the right-hand sidebar?

Comment: @Shog9: No. I right-clicked on Robert Harvey's comment.

Comment: Ah... That helps. There *was* a bug in the system that caused this - it was fixed. Marking this resolved.