# Received message stating I failed too many review audits?

Tags: support, review, review-audits, review-suspension

When clicking on the "review" tab today, I saw the following message:

> You have failed too many recent review audits – looks like you might need a break. Come back in 4 days to continue reviewing.

While I suppose I don't mind taking a break, I don't particularly remember failing any audits recently, so I'm not really sure why I've been banned.

Is there any way to check what behaviors might have gotten me banned so I can (at the very least) avoid doing whatever it is I did in the future?

Comment: I remember a post recently about one user getting screwed over after one failed audit; I'll link to it once I find it in case these have a similar underlying issue.

Comment: When you view your profile, you can go to the activity and review tab to check how you have done on recent reviews.

Comment: I did -- I check the last 3 or 4 pages, and the vast majority agreed with the consensus/were passed reviews. I didn't see any failed audits (although I suppose it's not impossible that I missed one)

Comment: Here we go: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202892/your-review-was-inappropriate Probably not related, but I wouldn't be terribly surprised if they ended up being so.

Comment: @Michael0x2a if the audits posts were deleted then they won't appear unfortunately.  Which review queue do you spend most of your time in?  Close?

Comment: @psubsee2003 -- I alternated between the close and suggested edit queues.

Comment: These are the only ones I could find: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3044676) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3140110) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3149723) -- But apparently you were banned by a moderator and not automatically.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3242344) was important; give me a bit to look for some other things. Also, you were going pretty fast (4 seconds per review). If you’re not a robot and just didn’t know code formatting wasn’t for emphasis (that might have been most of it), I’ll unban you :D Sorry.

Comment: Why in the hell do people approve edits like that one?

Comment: That should have been edited or rejected.

Comment: @minitech: Yeah -- I'll admit I was at fault there. I think I just saw emphasis, and saw that words that looked like code were looked like they were properly formatted, and jumped to conclusions. For the three questions animuson found, it looks like they were all from the reopen queue -- I think I'll probably avoid that queue for the time being, since I don't appear to have a good handle on them.