# Tag synonym : JVM and Java?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I have noticed that the tag [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm) was recently approved as a synonym to a tag [java](/questions/tagged/java).

I think there is a **substantial difference** between questions tagged as [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm) :

- [java](/questions/tagged/java) is for general questions about the Java **programming language**.
- [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm) is for questions related to implementation of a **virtual machine** that is running Java programs.

Furthermore, the tag wiki now defines that both [java](/questions/tagged/java) and [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm) are same - which is not true. I believe there is a difference between a language and its implementation.

Comment: more importantly, there's a difference between a language and the virtual machine it runs on

Comment: this sounds like vandalism. Wonder who approved. Wonder also if there was a jvm tag wiki lost when this happened, and is there a way to recover

Comment: plz merge [tag:x86] and [tag:c]? k thx bye.

Comment: But `c` **runs** on `x86`... So they are the same... right? **right?** ***RIGHT?!?!***

Comment: This is perfectly acceptable to me. In other news I hear math.se merged every tag to computation, they say it should make asking questions easier.

Comment: Next is [tag:java] -> [tag:javascript] right @JimmyHoffa ? :-D

Comment: @qwertynl we'll eventually get everything for [tag:turing-machine] that doesn't fit in [tag:regex].

Comment: @JanDvorak : Yes, but "a virtual machine" is in fact a subset of a "programming language implementation", isn't it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yeah, those aren't the same thing.  I removed the synonym.  Luckily the two tags were never merged, so 3978 [jvm](/questions/tagged/jvm) questions from before the synonym was created weren't retagged. About 100 were retagged while the synonym was active, so at least the damage was minimal.  Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: any details on who approved the synonym? I would expect at least some [manual review ban](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207409/165773) for letting a damage slip through