# bug with <sub> tags prevents editing/sharing or flagging

Tags: bug, design, markdown

I just saw an answer [here on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213831/241700) where the 
`share | edit | flag` and the `add comment`
links where not clickable.

I have since figured out how this is done, see here:
[Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/213841#213841) *****

It is just a matter of adding enough `<sub>` tags until the text moves below those links.

At least in Opera or Chrome this causes the links to be non-responding to mouse clicks.

Of course there are ways around that, but it is a bit annoying

Is this a known bug, or is it limited to my browsers?

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>***** let's see if it works for questions too... of course it works, now flag link is overlapped as well</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Hmmm, where, what?

Comment: The "flag" link works for me.

Comment: Not for me (in Chrome)

Comment: @Krampus sure you can click "flag" Check again. ;)

Comment: On Chrome Dev (latest build). I can't click it.

Comment: As an aside, [The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) is quite useful to remove stuf that's in your way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard [fixed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/213841/4) ;-)

Comment: @qwertynl genius! Too bad I can't grant a bounty to outstanding edit or comment!

Comment: Thanks! I would be happy to accept one anywhere else @ShadowWizard :-P

Comment: a while ago I [discovered this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/197804/9) ([plain-text](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/3697c749-1739-4ac2-b6c6-96f98f626ee4/view-source)), it makes the links unclickeable

Comment: No repo on iOS 7.0.3

Answer (score 5):

I use the following custom CSS:

```
sub sub { position: static }
```

Or, if you don't want the font-size to keep getting smaller the more subscripts you use:

```
sub sub { font-size: inherit; position: static }
```

Stack Exchange should consider implementing this simple solution. I just love simple solutions.

Comment: Simple solutions are simple.

Comment: Nice. And something similar for, say, [4 nested quotes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197517/nested-quote-trolling) might be easy too then.

Answer (score 3):

@animuson didn't have enough jQuery.

```
javascript:$('sub sub').css('position','static')
```

Save in bookmarklet, only click when needed, ???, profit.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a bug, it is a feature :-)

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>*It is not a bug, it is a feature!</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Comment: It seems [Shadow Wizard never told you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197517/nested-quote-trolling/208765#208765) how to protect the downvote button? ;-)

Comment: Emmmm I can Still downvote there @Arjan :-P